# Is it possile to determine the xl function name that called my XLL?

Tags: excel, xll

I have an xll with a c function registered several times in XL.

E.g. I register xllMyFunc as Fred and Joe so that I can put =Fred() or =Joe() in a spreadsheet.

Is there a way to determine if xllMyFunc() was called by Fred or by Joe?

Comment: Possibly by add # to the type string and calling a macro fn?

Comment: How about getting the formula text from the calling cell, and monitoring the number of calls from that cell into my xll, and determining from the formula and precidence which function is currently being called? Any easier way to do it?

Comment: Maybe you can create (possibly at runtime) some wrapper function that calls your function with an extra parameter indicating the actual registration.

Comment: I've found two xlls that can do this. pyxll and xpy so I think it must be possible.

Comment: The wrapper function won't work unless it knows what spreadsheet function xl was processing that caused it to call my xll. It the wrapper function knows that I can just use the same mechanism.

Comment: When your code is registering =Fred() and =Joe(), it might instead register wrapper functions that record which one was called, before calling xllMyFunc. Something like pyxll is effectively creating a wrapper on the fly, so one can imagine them adding some extra information. Anyway - Excel has nothing built in to help with this. Your other plan of checking the caller's formula would work too, but gets tricky as the formula gets complicated.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't possible. So I create a bunch of dummy methods (F1, F2, F3 etc) to map as needed. I use variable length C calls so I only can display the correct number of arguments in XL's function dialog.